# Why do ScrollViewer scroll to ItemsControl when an Item is removed?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

ScrollViewer seems to have a default behavior that makes it scroll to an ItemsControl when this ItemsControl's Items lose an element.

Take this example:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <ItemsControl>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Some item"/>
            </Button>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With ButtonBase_OnClick defined like this:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ((sender as Button).Parent as ItemsControl).Items.Remove(sender);
}
```

Before any action it looks like this:

[image: How it looks at the start]

But then, if I click on a button (which will remove itself from the ItemsControl):

[image: How it looks after an item get removed]

If I add a item instead of removing one it doesn't happen. How can I prevent this behavior?

**EDIT**

It doesn't happen if I add this code:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) => {
    new Thread(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {

            MyItemsControl.Items.Remove(MyItemsControl.Items[1]);
        }));
    }).Start();
};
```

But then, if I add:

```
(MyItemsControl.Items[1] as FrameworkElement).Focus();
```

Just before I remove it, the behavior happens.

So it's not when any Item get removed, but only if the Item has Focus. So a way to workaround this behavior would be to remove Focus from the Item before deleting it.

Is there a more convenient way to stop it from happening?

**Edit n°2**

I didn't specify that I'm using the framework .Net v3.5. I tried it with 4.5.1 after @Joseph's comment and indeed this doesn't happen in 4.5.1.

Comment: I've tried your code, and nothing of the scrolling you mentioned happens !!

Comment: @Joseph Edited my question: It seems to happen with framework 3.5 but not 4.5.1

Comment: And yu must use the .net 3.5 ?

Comment: @Joseph indeed. I create apps and components to integrate in a SCADA software that manages up to 3.5

Comment: This is a pretty annoying behavior,  even if you ScrollToTop() manually, that won't work without adding a delay!, hope some one could help...ps : tag the .Net3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (Obviously) that some extra scrolling events are fired, i tried to inspect all the event received by the `ScrollView` but still i didn't figured a proper work around this bug!

and since you needed to work with the .net 3.5 here an Old School hack, i hope it will help

**First** add a `ScrollChanged` event Handler and name your `ScrollViewer`

```
       <ScrollViewer x:Name="sc" ScrollChanged="Sc_OnScrollChanged">            
        <ItemsControl >              
            <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
```

**Second** change your codebehind to the following

```
 private int _cpt;
    private double _save;
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((sender as Button).Parent as ItemsControl).Items.Remove(sender);
        _cpt = 0;
    }              
    private void Sc_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cpt < 3)
        {
            if (_cpt == 0)
            {
                _save = sc.VerticalOffset;
            }
            //sc.ScrollToTop();
            sc.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_save);
            _cpt++;
        }

    }
```

it is kindof a Potato solution, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is really a tricky one, I am not sure if the below is the exact solution but it sure is a workaround.

The only change i did was add a line (i.e. to set focus from button or item-control to the parent or Window) after the item remove in click event.

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((sender as Button).Parent as ItemsControl).Items.Remove(sender);

        this.Focus();
    }
```

I ran a simple test with above and required behavior was achieved, do let me know if this is not what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried your code and indeed it works. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem because if I bind the ItemsSource of my ItemsControl to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel layer then I don't have access to the element to change its focus. This solution is also a bit random: put a Thread which sleeps 10ms and then change focus, it'll work 9 times out of 10. Sleep for 20 ms and it won't ever work. What's seems to be happening is that the Focus() call is processed before the UI is refreshed after the change on the Items collection. Thanks for your help!